# Camera Issue on iOS 10 with xam.Plugin.Media

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am using Xam.Plugin.Media (ver: 2.3.0) with Xamarin Forms for iOS.
It is working fine with IPhone with iOS-10 but the same code kick me out from the application when application is running on IPad with iOS-10.

Earlier, on iOS-9, it was working fine with iphone and ipad both.
I would looking forward for you reply.
Thanks

```
using Plugin.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace LearnForms.Pages
{
public class pgOpenCamera: ContentPage
{
private Image image1 { get; set; }
public StackLayout StkPage { get; set; }
public Button btnOpenCamera { get; set; }

public pgOpenCamera()
{
btnOpenCamera = new Button()
{
Text ="Open Camera!"
};
btnOpenCamera.Clicked += BtnOpenCamera_Clicked;
image1 = new Image();
StkPage = new StackLayout()
{
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,  
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
Padding = new Thickness(20),
Children = {btnOpenCamera, image1}
};
Content = StkPage;
}

private async void BtnOpenCamera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported) 
{
DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
return;
}
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
Directory = "Sample",
Name = "test.jpg"
});
if (file == null)
return;
DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
var stream = file.GetStream();
file.Dispose();
return stream;
});
} 
}
}
```

Qazi...

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin):

> Your app is required to have keys for NSCameraUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in order to access the device's camera and photo library. The string that you provide for each of these keys will be displayed to the user when they are prompted to provide permission to access these device features.

So I suggest you to add these to your Info.plist. Seems to be a change [since iOS 10](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/).